# CSS: Fixed Position of Parent Element

Tags: css, wrapper, css-position

In reference to the attached screenshot:

[image]

I want the position of the wrapper with the grey background to have a fixed width so that it aligns with the width of the pagination element above it.  Right now the width depends on the size of the children elements (the text or the text field).

In general, how would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided both sections are contined within the same container div, use a style of:

```
width:100%
```

Otherwise just specify your width to be the same as the pagination element...